Datables loading new pages and increase to actual page
I am using datatables and I am working with data coming from the server.
I'm working with datatables to list conversation data and I intend that every time I have new data I load the conversations on the final page.
My problem is when I have a user with many conversations, so I want to load 100 and 100 but I can't display the pagination control, I was trying to make it load another 100 records at the end of each scroll and include them in the previous table, but without having to make a call to the server with all the messages to avoid overload.
Every time I run Datatables the page is rebuilt with the new data, losing the previous view. I would like to add new records to the current table without letting the table reload.
The code below is the attempts I made and it didn't work, it's always the same result.
$('#contacts-table tbody').scroll(function() {
      if (typeof(lastScrollTop) == "undefined") {
        lastScrollTop = 0;     
      }

      var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
      var scrollHeight = $(this).prop('scrollHeight');
      var offsetHeight = $(this).prop('offsetHeight');
      var pagination = $('#contacts-table').DataTable().page.info();

      console.log(scrollTop)
      if (scrollTop > lastScrollTop && ((scrollTop) == (scrollHeight - offsetHeight)) && pagination.end != pagination.recordsTotal) {
        //console.log("foi" + scrollTop + " -- " + scrollHeight+ " -- " + offsetHeight)
       // $("#contacts-table tbody").on('DOMSubtreeModified',function(){
          console.log("The text has been changed. "+scrollTop);
         // $('#contacts-table').DataTable().page(0).draw(true);
         // $('#contacts-table').DataTable().page(1).draw(true);
          //$('#contacts-table').DataTable().page(2).draw(true);
          //$('#contacts-table').DataTable().len(-1).draw();
          //data = $('#contacts-table').DataTable().rows().data();
          //for (let i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            //console.log(table.row(i).data().email)
          //}
          //$('#contacts-table').DataTable().ajax.reload( null, false );
          //console.log(data);
          //$(this).scrollTop(scrollTop);
        //});
        $('#contacts-table').DataTable().page('next').draw(false);
        //$('#contacts-table').DataTable().order([[1, 'asc']]).draw(false);
        //table.draw();
        }

      lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
    });

I want to load new pages or new results and include them in the current table without losing previous data and without having to load all the data. Example of programming logic:

Loading 1: (Registers from 1 to 100)

Current table displays: Loading 1

Scroll goes to the end

Load 2: Load new records (Records 101 to 200)

Adds Load 2 records to the current table

Current table displays: Loading 1 and Loading 2


